# Equivalence of algorithms with less than vs equal to constrains

Tags: algorithms, reductions

*Problem A:*

Given an algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ for $(I,k)$,$k\in \mathbb{N}$, $A$ return true $\iff$ There exist a subset $S\subseteq I$ s.t $|S| \le k$ some property hold.

*Problem B:*

Given an algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ for $(I,k)$,$k\in \mathbb{N}$, $A$ return true $\iff$ There exist a subset $S\subseteq I$ s.t $|S|=k$ some property hold.

Is there a generic way of constructing a solution for *Problem B* using the algorithm for *Problem A*?

For example:

Given an algorithm for [Subset Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) **decision problem** with slight variation, assume that the algorithm returns Yes if it has a subset in size less than $k$ that sum to some $t$ and K-Sum problem [a generalization for the 3-Sum description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM)

Is there a way to construct a solution for the K-Sum?
I am not asking specifically for those algorithms but in general.

Can it always be done? Are there special cases?

Comment: In your example the property is on $S$ in its entirety. But when you described "problem A" and "problem B", the property needs to be held independently by all values of $S$ that are smaller than $k$. The two things are *totally* different. Are you sure about the definitions?

Comment: The property should hold for the entire subgroup $S$ and not independently. I added a clarafication.

Comment: Is $k \in N$ (or other countable set)?

Comment: Yes, $k$ only indicate the group size

Comment: There is no generic way, since it could be that the property trivially holds for the trivial subgroup, making problem A trivial (by the way, I suspect that you actually mean subset; the two have very different meanings in mathematical English).

Comment: Yes, Thank you for the correction. I have edited the question. Can you supply an example?